# Serious clang bug for compiling arm code

Tags: android-ndk, arm, clang

Yesterday, I found a catastrophic problem in `clang` when I was trying to compile a code for arm (in android arm-v7a at least). See this small code:

```
void init_c_32(uint8_t *ptr)
{
    uint32_t tmp[SIZE];
    memcpy(tmp, ptr, 33);
}
```

here is the generated assembly code for calling `memcpy` here:

```
0x7903d714 <+20>: ldr    r0, [sp, #0x10]
0x7903d716 <+22>: add    r3, sp, #0x14
0x7903d718 <+24>: mov.w  r12, #0x20
0x7903d71c <+28>: str    r0, [sp, #0xc]
0x7903d71e <+30>: mov    r0, r3
0x7903d720 <+32>: ldr    r3, [sp, #0xc]
0x7903d722 <+34>: str    r1, [sp, #0x8]
0x7903d724 <+36>: mov    r1, r3
0x7903d726 <+38>: str    r2, [sp, #0x4]
0x7903d728 <+40>: mov    r2, r12
0x7903d72a <+42>: blx    0x7903d658                ; symbol stub for: __aeabi_memcpy
```

which uses `__aeabi_memcpy` and everything will be ok for any `ptr` address. Now if we change argument type to `uint32_t *`, generated assembly code will change as follows:

```
void init_c_32(uint32_t *ptr)
{
    uint32_t tmp[SIZE];
    memcpy(tmp, ptr, 33);
}

0x790456dc <+20>: ldr    r0, [sp, #0x8]
0x790456de <+22>: add    r3, sp, #0xc
0x790456e0 <+24>: ldm.w  r0!, {r4, r5, r12, lr}
0x790456e4 <+28>: stm.w  r3!, {r4, r5, r12, lr}
0x790456e8 <+32>: ldm.w  r0, {r4, r5, r12, lr}
0x790456ec <+36>: stm.w  r3, {r4, r5, r12, lr}
```

This code is optimized a lot and uses `ldm.w` and `stm.w` rather than `memcpy`. Result is a much quicker code, but there is a drawback. This code will not work correctly with odd `ptr` addresses and creates `SIGBUS` exception which is correct based on generated assembly code. `.w` addressing limits addressing model to even values, but maybe we can say that this is by design because we have defined argument as `unit32_t *` and we say that this argument must be aligned.

**But** main problem happens here. Check following code:

```
void init_c_32(__packed uint32_t *ptr)
{
    uint32_t tmp[SIZE];
    memcpy(tmp, ptr, 33);
}
```

as you see, event though we have specified `uint32_t *` as input parameter, we have used `__packed` specifier. As [standard](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0491e/CJAFJHJD.html) specifies, `__packed` says that:

> objects of packed type are read or written using unaligned accesses.

But when we see generated assembly code, we see the following:

```
0x78ec56dc <+20>: ldr    r0, [sp, #0x8]
0x78ec56de <+22>: add    r3, sp, #0xc
0x78ec56e0 <+24>: ldm.w  r0!, {r4, r5, r12, lr}
0x78ec56e4 <+28>: stm.w  r3!, {r4, r5, r12, lr}
0x78ec56e8 <+32>: ldm.w  r0, {r4, r5, r12, lr}
0x78ec56ec <+36>: stm.w  r3, {r4, r5, r12, lr}
```

As you see, generated code does not differ with a non `__packed` mode and this conflicts with `ARM` standard. You still cannot use odd addresses for referencing and you will get `SIGBUS` exception. I think in this case generated code should be similar to when we use `uint8_t *` as argument.

**I think this is a very serious bug** and can created unexpected results and any good solution is welcomed.

I have used ndk 16 for this creating this problem which uses `clang 5.0.3` as its compiler.

Current workaround is using `uint8_t *` as input all the time which creates correct code. But efficiency-wise, it will be better if this problem is solved.

Comment: Usually bugs are reported to upstream, not SO. Try http://llvm.org/bugs/

Comment: @arrowd sadly registration is now closed and has became email only. that's why I wrote it here so other people know about it too.

Comment: You are encouraged to [open an issue](https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/new) for Android NDK, too.

Comment: I dont see a bug here yet...This is standard operation, you should avoid unaligned addresses, if you want this code to work then you need to disable the unaligned trap in the processor.  Feeding unaligned addresses into a processor that is set to trap unaligned addresses, a setting the compiler has nothing to do with, is not the compilers fault.  The best solution no matter what platform you are on is to never generate unaligned reasons.  It is disturbing that ARM now allows unaligned addresses, better to just not generate that code.

Comment: Are you that desperate for data space that you need to pack structures and deal with their side effects?  This is a well known side effect of packing structures.

Comment: Since you are likely not in control of alignment for that platform, then you need to generate code compatible with that platform, you asked the compiler to generate unaligned code for an aligned platform, and it appears that it did what you asked.  The programmer knows if the platform traps unaligned accesses, the compiler cannot know this without the programmer telling the tool, so as the responsible party you should not be telling the compiler to generate code that wont work on the platform, not the compilers problem to solve.

Comment: @old_timer no, `__packed` means that address you are accessing can be unaligned. so the generate code must access it in a way that you won't get `SIGBUS` for unaligned memory access. at least ARM C compiler works like this.

Comment: that is not possible, makes no sense whatsoever, you the programmer knows what causes a sigbus since the compiler has zero power over that you are responsible not the compiler.  This is not new in any way, it has been well known for a very long time a couple of decades or more, if you are just now learning this then that is another story.  the memcpy aspect to this is irrelelvant using __packed against an aligned only system will create code that doesnt work, and is the programmers responsibility.

Comment: the most important question is why do you think you need to pack structures on a system like this anyway?  why create the alignment nightmare problem for yourself (not the compiler).  how many bytes are you really saving?  you are using a compiler if you are that tight on bytes you might think about not wasting so much space using a compiler...

Comment: @old_timer, there are situations where packed structures are legitimate, e.g. network stream or file access. Your *how many bytes are you really saving* argument is not applicable here, because the alignment requirements on the machine that wrote this stream could be different.

Comment: I suspected that was what you are doing and that is a text book example of an improper misuse of structures.  that is in the application specific area of the language so no guarantee that it does what you think it does across compile domains.  so you are using an application specific misuse of the languge with an application specific option, against an aligned target, and somehow its the compilers fault for all of this.  this is 100% programmers error from beginning to end.

Comment: NEVER use structures across compile domains, that is just very very bad.  and then dont carry the well known side effects that come from trying to hack at using structures across compile domains.

Comment: sorry meant to say "implementation defined" not application defined...

Comment: this is pretty much what happens one implementation of C is assumed to be actually C then when moving to another implementation be the same tool with a different target or a different tool, this happens.  which is why it is often 10+ to 20+ years before some folks see issues with these habits, for various work or personal reasons stay within one or a few toolchains (implementations of the language) for years or decades and develop habits which are very hard to break.

Comment: because of gcc and clang the number of mainstream compilers and thus different implementations of the language are reducing we are seeing this habit becoming a FAD.  perhaps it will cause some nth version of the language spec to address it in a specific way, and then have to wait for a while for the compilers to adapt to that. (and the majority of other remaining versions to become non-compliant putting is back in the situation of professionally never doing such a thing because we have to work with these tools, compliant or not).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FWIW, **clang**, unlike the ARM C compiler, does not allow `__packed` pointers. For **clang**, `__packed` is a synonym for `__attribute__((__packed__))` which only applies to enum, struct, or union: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3/gcc/Type-Attributes.html.

Comment: But problem is that code generation in gcc always uses call for `memcpy` and then `SIGBUS` exception will not happen for unaligned access. `clang` optimization is great, but at same time creates this problem. it is true that `__packed` is equal to `__attribute__((__packed__))`, but I think generated code should not create this behavior. Maybe I'm wrong, but I think `clang`'s approach is not correct.

Comment: For me, Clang legitimately warns that the attribute is ignored. After this warning, it is not obliged to respect the attribute.

Comment: memcpy is not relevant here your packed structure can/will generate alignment faults, if you are not seeing those then it is just a matter of time or dumb luck.

Comment: at best this could be a bug in that the compiler didnt ignore the request and/or the compiler failed to warn that the code wouldnt work

Comment: But there is another difference between `gcc` and `clang` that escalate this problem. I had a small structure like `struct {char a; char b[4];} c;`. In `gcc`, generated code aligns `b` on 4 bytes boundary. But `clang` does not do this for `b` and its address becomes odd. So now if for any reason, I have accessed `b`'s address by casting it like `*(uint32_t*)(&(c.b))`, it may create same problem. The main problem is that you cannot predict this problem can happen. only adding a 1 byte member to structure can create odd address for other structure members and `SIGBUS`.

Comment: btw, I found https://git.ics.ele.tue.nl/5LIM0-sources/llvm/commit/635f4a3264343e83f5c5e8b6f6e2be5571889005 too and I think it is related to this problem. I didn't have any problem with `clang` with older `ndk`, but it happened in `ndk` 16.

Comment: maybe you should check what assembly is generated for a function with parameter of type `__packed struct { char a; uint8_t b[4] }` that memcpy's **b**.